# Django Generic Views using decorator login_required

Tags: django

I'm new with django and I finished the 4 part tutorial on djangoproject.com

My problem is I want to put a login authentication on my polls app. I've use the decorator @login_required and it works properly but under my views.py I have only vote() method.

my views.py under "polls folder"

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import RequestContext
from polls.models import Poll, Choice


@login_required
@never_cache
def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('poll_results', args=(p.id,)))
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on poll %s." % poll_id)
```

my urls.py under "polls folder"

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from polls.models import Poll

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5],
            context_object_name = 'latest_poll_list',
            template_name = 'polls/index.html'), name='poll_lists'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model = Poll,
            template_name = 'polls/detail.html'), name='poll_details'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model = Poll,
            template_name = 'polls/results.html'), name = 'poll_results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'polls.views.vote'),
)
```

under my urls.py I have use generic views.

Problem is: how will I put login required under the "index" of the polls app. So that the user will login first before he/she can view the available polls.

Current is: I have used login required under my views.py and method vote(), It will require login after voting.

anyone can help me out?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**1nd approach**

In urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        login_required(ListView.as_view(
            queryset = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5],
            context_object_name = 'latest_poll_list',
            template_name = 'polls/index.html'), name='poll_lists')),
)
```

**2nd approach**

In views.py:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    queryset = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context_object_name = 'latest_poll_list'
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):        
        return super(IndexView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

then in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$',
            IndexView.as_view(), name='poll_lists'),
    )
```

Comment: Caught ImportError while rendering: cannot import name ListVieiw << I get this error when I use your urls.py answer

Comment: You have got `IndexView` in `views.py` so you need to import this class to `urls.py`. Put to the beginning of `urls.py` this line `from polls.views import IndexView`

Comment: In template /home/justin/Workspace/training/django/sample/mysite/templates/base.html, error at line 21
Caught ImportError while rendering: cannot import name ListVieiw

Comment: <li><a href="{% url home %}">Home</a></li> << my line 21 code under base.html

Comment: Typo `ListVieiw` -> `ListView`

Comment: thanks! maybe I insert the "i" because i'm using vim as editor.. hehehe.. wait, I will try again your solution

Comment: It's not relevant to this question. Do you mean `self.request.user`?

Comment: what is `method_decorator()` ? Django tell me that's not define.

Answer (score 19):

Just providing a potentially more up-to-date answer,

I would move them to a views file and use the [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin),

```
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView
)
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class PollsListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Poll
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
```

Comment: when i going to a url that have `LoginRequiredMixin` nothing happend.